LVGL output in new version is not as in version 5.3
I used to generate C arrays for my fonts using the online font converter version 5.3 using this link https://lvgl.io/tools/font_conv_v5_3
The generated arrays used to have the character as comments beside the code itself as in this screenshot

The glyph descriptors used to be simple with w_px and glyph_index only

This used to work fine with my code
Currently as the link to font converter 5,3 is not valid anymore, when I try to create a C array with the current font converter I get completely different output with a much bigger glyph descriptor and there is no symbol for the character as comments beside the code itself.

I also tried to run the offline tool https://github.com/lvgl/lv_font_conv  but the output was the same
lv_font_conv --font JetBrainsMono-Bold.ttf -r 0x20-0x7f --size 24 --format lvgl --lv-include lvgl.h --bpp 1 -o myfont.c

Is there a way that I can get the same output as before?
